# Groupby with conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pd.DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
In [30]: df
Out[30]: 
        DATES  UID      A
0  2014-01-01    1  False
1  2014-01-02    2  False
2  2014-01-03    3   True
3  2014-01-04    4   True
4  2014-01-05    5  False
5  2014-01-06    6   True
6  2014-01-07    1  False
7  2014-01-08    2  False
8  2014-01-09    3  False
9  2014-01-10    2  False
10 2014-01-11    3  False
11 2014-01-12    4  False
12 2014-01-13    5  False
13 2014-01-14    3  False
14 2014-01-15    1  False
```

and I would like to find a way to:

1. Order by DATES ASC
2. Group by UID
3. Filter out all UID's where the first entry (per UID) has 'A' == False

The desired output would look like this:

```
In [30]: df
Out[30]: 
    DATES  UID      A
0  2014-01-03    3   True
1  2014-01-04    4   True
2  2014-01-06    6   True
3  2014-01-09    3  False
4  2014-01-11    3  False
5  2014-01-12    4  False
6  2014-01-14    3  False
```

Any ideas very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you show your efforts, for instance have you tried [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with `groupby` like this: In [31]: df123 = df.sort_values(by='DATES').groupby('UID')

In [32]: df123
Out[32]: <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x1160d5898> and it's an object that is created, not sure how to filter out the right entries though.

Comment: Please edit your question with your attempts

Comment: The docs clearly state that you will receive a `GroupBy` Object. The examples below the function outline show you how to access the desired columns from that object: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: @jbndlr Thanks, I guess I was not sure how to filter on the returned object. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like need first [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
df.sort_values(by='DATES', inplace=True)
df = df.groupby('UID', sort=False).filter(lambda x: x.A.iloc[0] == True)
print (df)
        DATES  UID      A
2  2014-01-03    3   True
3  2014-01-04    4   True
5  2014-01-06    6   True
8  2014-01-09    3  False
10 2014-01-11    3  False
11 2014-01-12    4  False
13 2014-01-14    3  False
```

Comment: Was helpful to see how to filter the first values for each group, thanks!